# É possível colocar um arquivo HMTL dentro do banco de dados?

Tags: php, html, sql, banco-de-dados, blob

É possível guardar um arquivo HTML em uma coluna `BLOB` dentro do banco de dados e depois exibir como parte da página no PHP?

Porque fazer isso: é mais para um experimento de aprendizagem para comparar se fica melhor que um `include` na página.

Comment: Qualquer coisa com `echo` faz parte do HTML. Logo, se vc puxar do banco um registro com código HTML e fizer um `echo`, será renderizado como HTML.

Comment: Então em pratica ficaria a mesma coisa? ou mais lento?

Comment: Mais lento porque tem que fazer requisição ao banco antes. Ao meu ver isso não é uma boa prática, já que existe include para essa função.

Comment: Sim é totalmente possível, na verdade é como CMS como WordPress funcionam.

Comment: Sim, tem muitas maneiras de fazer isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O arquivo em si não é possível, afinal arquivo é um conceito do sistema de arquivos do sistema operacional, mas um texto que seja um HTML é totalmente possível. Nem precisa ser um `BLOB`. Pode ser esse tipo de coluna, mas pode ser um `TEXT` ou `VARCHAR` e até mesmo um `CHAR` embora provavelmente bastante inadequado. Você não precisa ter um arquivo para gerar o conteúdo, o que será entregue precisa ser um texto reconhecido como HTML, só isto.

Claro, é função da sua aplicação entregar de forma adequada para o servidor HTTP para que este HTML seja enviado para o cliente quando tiver uma requisição. Sua aplicação pode pegar este HTML de onde for, pode compor várias partes, você pode fazer o que desejar. Se conseguir compor de forma coerente é uma ferramenta bastante poderosa para dar flexibilidade no resultado.

Deve evitar abusos, tem que cuidar da segurança, pode não ser o que dá mais performance, pode não ser o mais adequado para o que precisa, mas estas são outros questões.

Já posso adiantar que não fica melhor que o `include`, só faça uso de um banco de dados se for necessário.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu salvaria no tipo varbinary e recuperar byte[] para depois converter em string.